# Zapier Lead Validation CRM

Tags: zapier, make.com

CRM LEAD VALIDATION

Hello guys, I have 2 scenarios that I want to validate.

1- New lead - Phone number doesn't exist in my CRM.

Example: Get lead from facebook lead ad to my CRM (Powelink), and the lead get in to new clients section.

2- Existing lead - Phone number exist in my CRM.

Example: Get lead from facebook lead ad to my CRM, the CRM recognize that the phone number is existing -> send it to "Existing customer" Section.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

**You can't do it as long as Powerlink is not available on Zapier.**
Here's the list of CRMs that have Zapier integrations: https://zapier.com/apps/categories/crm

#### Long answer

Zapier offers Facebook Lead Ads integrations and setting up a trigger when a new lead is captured is possible. However, Powerlink is not in the list of the CRMs supported by Zapier, so you can't go anywhere after the trigger. For most of the CRMs integrations, Zapier offers a find action where you can optionally create a new customer when the search fails. This kind of action would have been perfect for you.